# Sadhus giving curses or boons in Kalyug

Tags: curse

As we see in Hindu mythology and Epics, Sadhus curses or boons were becoming real. The reason for this was because of their penances of so many years.

Can Sadhus curses or boons come real in Kalyug?
[image]